# How to solve BindException error in my TCP connection program

Tags: java, tcp, rsa

I have two classes, Alice and Bob and I'm using them to practise RSA encryption by sending Alice's public key to Bob who uses it to encrypt a message which is then sent as ciphertext back to Alice for decryption.
I keep getting a BindEcxeption error but even when I try to change the port numbers.

This is the Alice code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Alice {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        int bitLength = 512;
        SecureRandom randomNum = new SecureRandom();
        
        int certainty = 50; // 1 - 1/2(50) certainty
        
        //Calculating p, q and n(public key)
        BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bitLength, certainty, randomNum);
        BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bitLength, certainty, randomNum);
        BigInteger n = calculateMod(p,q);
        
        //Calculating phiN
        BigInteger phiN = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        
        //Calculating e
        BigInteger e  = new BigInteger("65537");
        
        //Calculate private key
        BigInteger d = e.modInverse(phiN);
        
        //TCP Socket creation and sending of data
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")   
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(49999);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        pw.println(n);
        pw.flush();
        
        System.out.println("Connected");
        
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
        String sent = bufferedReader.readLine();
        BigInteger sentCipher = new BigInteger(sent);
        
        //Decryption
        BigInteger decryptedMessage = sentCipher.modPow(d, n);
        System.out.println("Number message sent was " + decryptedMessage);
        
        
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateMod(BigInteger p, BigInteger q) {
        BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
        return n;
    }
    
    
}
```

This is the Bob code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Taking user message input
        System.out.println("Enter number message: ");
        BigInteger message = scanner.nextBigInteger();
        
        //Calculating e
        BigInteger e  = new BigInteger("65537");
        
        //TCP Socket creation
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(49999);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        
        System.out.println("Connected");
        
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
        
        String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
        BigInteger publicKey = new BigInteger(str);
        
        //Encryption
        BigInteger ciphertext = message.modPow(e, publicKey);
        
        //Sending ciphertext
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        pw.println(ciphertext);
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:479)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:468)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:396)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:282)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:173)
        at Bob.main(Bob.java:20)**
```

I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if the issue is obvious.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use the same port as ServerPort twice. One component is the client (sender) and one is the server (receiver). You might want to have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: That solved it.
Works just fine now.